# How can I assign a session key with Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, session

I have a PHP program, called login.

When the user passes something, like email and password, `login.php` will return a session key to the user, if the login succeeds.

And I have JavaScript code to call this function to do the login.

How can I store this session key to identify whether the user is logged in?

Comment: you cant set a session using javascript... you can do cookie instead but cookies are not secure... but if you want to access the session value you can print $_SESSION['key'] in your js code(if the js code exist in .php file)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session is stored in a cookie by the server.
You don't need to do anything on the client.

Answer (score 0):

a session is serverside.. not clientside.. so you cant set it through js

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are declared manually like this:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username']; // or any other variable
```

You can then check on the other pages with PHP like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){

    //do this if true

}
```